# malloc of pointer to structure works why?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, structure, sizeof

In a code I accidentally used

```
    list* Head = malloc(sizeof(list*));
```

instead of the correct

```
    list* Head = malloc(sizeof(list));
```

to create a new `list` type node but it worked just fine later on.

So my question is why did it work properly?

Comment: What do you mean worked? Compilation succeeded or your program worked fine?

Comment: compilation succeeded and when i debugged it stored the int value and showed it in memory too

Comment: Either `sizeof(list*)` is greater than or equal to `sizeof(list)` or you had **undefined behaviour**.

Comment: Always use `T* variable = malloc(sizeof * variable);` to avoid these kind of errors.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala size of list is 8 and pointer is 4 node comprised of int and pointer of structure type

Comment: so, `sizeof(list *)` wasn't greater than or equal to `sizeof(list)`, therefore you had undefined behaviour. If you use `gcc`, try compiling with `-fsanitize=undefined`.

Comment: Im using eclipse Luna with MinGW compiler. And yes sizeof(list *) is less then sizeof(list) (I checked). But shouldn't undefined behavior atleast once give faulty behavior. Also using debug tool of eclipse the memory addresses and values are same

Comment: @muhammadshoaib be aware that undefined behaviour includes "apparently working fine". Google it. Your fauly program may work 100 times and fail the 101st time. Or if you compile and runit on another computer it may fail each time, or anything else may happen.

Comment: hmm Ill keep that in mind Thank you all for helping me out

Comment: @MichaelWalz True. You could write a compiler that produces a program that formats your harddrive when this happens, and you could still claim that it follows the standard, since the standard does not say anything about how undefined behavior should be treated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The idea here is, `malloc()` has no idea (type/size) or relation to the variable to which the return value is going to be assigned. It takes the input argument, allocates memory of the requested size and returns a pointer to the memory block, that's it. So, in case, you have requested for an erroneous size of memory block, `malloc()` has nothing to prevent you from doing that. Once you use the returned pointer, you'll either be

- wasting memory, when the allocated size is more than required for target type.
- cause [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) by accessing out of bound memory, when the requested size is lesser than required as per target type.

Now, in either case, you may see it *working properly*. The former is *somewhat* permissible (though should be avoided) but the later is a strict no-go.

---

Word of advice:

To avoid these type of mistakes, use the format

```
  type * variable = malloc(sizeof *variable);
```

in that case, you have two advantages,

1. Your statement is decoupled with the type of the variable.
2. The chances of mistyping the required size is less.